# reduce [ { x: 2 }, { x: 22 }, { x: 42 } ] with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reduce

Any suggestions on how to understand why the first reduce call results in NaN but the second one results in 22?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```
let maxCallback = ( acc, cur ) => Math.max( acc.x, cur.x );


// reduce without initialValue
[ { x: 2 }, { x: 22 }, { x: 42 } ].reduce( maxCallback ); // NaN
[ { x: 2 }, { x: 22 }            ].reduce( maxCallback ); // 22
```

Comment: `let maxCallback = ( acc, cur ) => Math.max( acc.x, cur.x );` should be `let maxCallback = ( acc, cur ) => Math.max( acc, cur.x );`

Comment: `acc` is a number, `acc.x` is undefined. The callback should be `Math.max(acc, cur.x )`

Comment: Never call `reduce` without an initial value!

Comment: this explains why the second reduce statements works "If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used and skipped." It is straight from the same link I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduce function should return an object with the same format as the ones in the array:

```
let maxCallback = ( acc, cur ) => ({ x: Math.max( acc.x, cur.x )});
```

Answer (score 2):

An [`initialValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is needed in order to apply the initial return onto some value.

- `acc` is our **Integer** (that starts at `0`)
- `cur` is the **Object** from which we reduce it's `x` property value
- Therefore use the second *initialValue* parameter `.reduce( maxCallback, 0 )`
- Assign like `acc = Math.max( acc, cur.x )`
- Implicitly return `, acc)`

```js
let maxCallback = ( acc, cur ) => (acc = Math.max( acc, cur.x ), acc);

// reduce with initialValue
const a = [ { x: 2 }, { x: 22 }, { x: 42 } ].reduce( maxCallback, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER ); // 42
const b = [ { x: 2 }, { x: 22 }            ].reduce( maxCallback, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER ); // 22

console.log(a, b)
```

---

The *initialValue* **is optional** and useful - but when you don't reduce two different *Types* like Object to Number - but **Number to Number** like:

```js
let maxCallback = ( acc, cur ) => (acc = Math.max( acc, cur ), acc);

// reduce without initialValue
const a = [ 2, 22, 42 ].reduce( maxCallback ); // 42
const b = [ 2, 22     ].reduce( maxCallback ); // 22

console.log(a, b)
```

Comment: This explains why the second reduce statements works "If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used and skipped." It is straight from the same link I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @RajKon yes, this explains everything